# re.sub - File path

Tags: python, regex

I have a file name `test.CSV` and I want to replace with `.xlsx`. I want the use the `re` module to use the case insensitive feature. I just can't seem to figure this out:

```
test = re.compile('test.CSV', re.IGNORECASE)
test.sub('.xlsx', '.csv')
'.csv'
```

What am I missing? Seems like such a simple problem.

Comment: Your regex should be `r'(test)\.CSV'` and replacement should be `r'\1.xlsx'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the regex:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\.CSV', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> pattern.sub(repl='.xlsx', string='test.CSV')
'test.xlsx'
>>> pattern.sub(repl='.xlsx', string='test.csv')
'test.xlsx'
```

Not using regex in the first place:

```
base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
if ext.lower() == '.csv':
    fname = base + '.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're compiling a pattern, the first argument to [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) has to be the pattern to replace. In your case, it should've been `\.csv`. However, for this specific case, I don't see any benefit in pre-compiling unless you use the same pattern multiple times.

So, using the top-level [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function should be sufficient:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.csv', r'\.xlsx', 'test.CSV', flags=re.I)
'test\\.xlsx'
```

If not, compile and use the pattern like this:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'\.csv', flags=re.I)
>>> p.sub(r'\.xslx', 'test.CSV')
'test\\.xslx'
```

Comment: @wim I ran this on python3.6 and it said nothing

Comment: Then you probably have warnings turned off.  Run `python3.6 -Wall` to enable them.

Comment: @wim Regardless of whether you downvoted or not, thanks for pointing out my mistake. I never knew python had a -Wall feature at all. Nice!